# OrientDB query friend of friend in social network

Tags: orientdb

I have a question regarding how to create an OrientDB query. 
The query should count the vertices of friends of friends relation in depths.

I am running OrientDB 2.1.6.

Schema:
Person is a Vertex, with property id (int)
Friend is an Edge

The relations I am looking for are like this:

Person -- Friend--> Person -- Friend --> Person
(#12:0)             (#12:1)             (#12:2)

I have 1 milion vertex and 100 milion edges.
Each vertex have 100 edges with random vertexes.

I want to start in vertex #12:0 and count how many vertex I have in depths 2,3,4 and 5.
I want to compare the query performance in milliseconds with Neo4j.

Can someone help me? 
How is the fastest way to query this on OrientDB?
Sorry for the bad english.

Thank you guys

Answer (score 1):

If you want to obtain the number of vertices at depth 2, the number of vertices at depth 3, etc you can use this query

```
select $depth,count(*) from (traverse out() from #12:0 while $depth<=5) where $depth>=2 group by $depth
```

if you want to sum how many vertices there are at depth 2,3,4,5
you can use this query

```
select count(*) from (traverse out() from #12:0 while $depth<=5) where $depth>=2
```

Comment: You will probably want to use out('Friend') rather than just out(), since there might be other types of outward-bound edges in the database.

Comment: even better, you can use both('Friend') if the edge direction does not have a  meaning in your domain (eg. if I'm your friend you are supposed to be my friend as well)

Comment: also, as per documentation, if you have a fixed depth, then you can do
out('Friend').out('Friend') for 2 level depth, and it would be faster.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `select @rid,out("Friend").size() from (traverse out() from #12:0 while $depth<=5)`

Regards